# C code with vector instrinsics for Riscv Vector

Tags: assembly, simd, simulator, riscv, riscv32

I have simulated bare-metal General purpose Riscv programs on spike. Now I want to run bare-metal vector program on spike but I think that the C program that will be used to cross compile and generate a log file through spike will be built differently than for the general purpose. But I can't find any documentations for simulating vector on spike. Can anyone please guide me through this?

I have configured my toolchain and spike for for rv64 gcv and have tried making main functions having vector intrinsics, but despite of getting vector instructions on the assembly file generated by the toolchain, my log file contains only General purpose instructions.

This is my C program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <riscv_vector.h>

volatile uint64_t tohost __attribute__((section(".tohost")));
volatile uint64_t fromhost __attribute__((section(".fromhost")));

void saxpy(size_t n, const double a, const double *x, double *y) {
    size_t vl;
    vfloat64m8_t vx, vy;
    for (; n > 0; n -= vl) {
        vl = vsetvl_e64m8(n);
        vx = vle64_v_f64m8(x, vl);
        vy = vle64_v_f64m8(y, vl);
        vy = vfmsac_vf_f64m8(vy, a, vx, vl);
        vse64_v_f64m8(y, vy, vl);
        x += vl;
        y += vl;
    }

    // Signal completion to the "tohost" register after the loop
    tohost = 1;
}

int main() {
    const size_t array_size = 8;
    const double a = 2.0;
    double x[array_size];
    double y[array_size];

    // Initialize arrays x and y with data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        x[i] = (double)(i + 1);      // Values 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ..., 8.0
        y[i] = (double)((i + 1) * 10); // Values 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, ..., 80.0
    }

    saxpy(array_size, a, x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the assembly generated by toolchain:

```
    .file   "vector.c"
    .option nopic
    .attribute arch, "rv64i2p0_m2p0_a2p0_f2p0_d2p0_c2p0_v1p0_zve32f1p0_zve32x1p0_zve64d1p0_zve64f1p0_zve64x1p0_zvl128b1p0_zvl32b1p0_zvl64b1p0"
    .attribute unaligned_access, 0
    .attribute stack_align, 16
    .text
    .globl  tohost
    .section    .tohost,"aw"
    .align  3
    .type   tohost, @object
    .size   tohost, 8
tohost:
    .zero   8
    .globl  fromhost
    .section    .fromhost,"aw"
    .align  3
    .type   fromhost, @object
    .size   fromhost, 8
fromhost:
    .zero   8
    .text
    .align  1
    .globl  saxpy
    .type   saxpy, @function
saxpy:
    addi    sp,sp,-64
    sd  s0,56(sp)
    addi    s0,sp,64
    csrr    t0,vlenb
    slli    t1,t0,4
    sub sp,sp,t1
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-24
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    sd  a0,0(a5)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-32
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    sd  a1,0(a5)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-40
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    sd  a2,0(a5)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-48
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    sd  a3,0(a5)
    j   .L2
.L3:
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-24
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a5,0(a5)
    vsetvli a5,a5,e64,m8,ta,mu
    sd  a5,-24(s0)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,3
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a3,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-40
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a2,0(a5)
    ld  a4,-24(s0)
    vsetvli zero,a4,e64,m8,ta,mu
    vle64.v v24,(a2)
    vs8r.v  v24,0(a3)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a3,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-48
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a2,0(a5)
    ld  a4,-24(s0)
    vle64.v v24,(a2)
    vs8r.v  v24,0(a3)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a3,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a2,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-32
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a4,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,3
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    vl8re64.v   v24,0(a2)
    fld fa5,0(a4)
    vl8re64.v   v8,0(a5)
    ld  a4,-24(s0)
    vsetvli zero,a4,e64,m8,tu,mu
    vfmsac.vf   v24,fa5,v8
    vs8r.v  v24,0(a3)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-48
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a4,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a3,0(a4)
    vl8re64.v   v24,0(a5)
    ld  a4,-24(s0)
    vsetvli zero,a4,e64,m8,ta,mu
    vse64.v v24,(a3)
    ld  a5,-24(s0)
    slli    a3,a5,3
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-40
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a4,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-40
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a5,0(a5)
    add a5,a5,a3
    sd  a5,0(a4)
    ld  a5,-24(s0)
    slli    a3,a5,3
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-48
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a4,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-48
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a5,0(a5)
    add a5,a5,a3
    sd  a5,0(a4)
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-24
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a4,a5,s0
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-24
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a3,0(a5)
    ld  a5,-24(s0)
    sub a5,a3,a5
    sd  a5,0(a4)
.L2:
    csrr    a5,vlenb
    neg a5,a5
    slli    a5,a5,4
    addi    a5,a5,-24
    addi    a5,a5,-16
    add a5,a5,s0
    ld  a5,0(a5)
    bne a5,zero,.L3
    lui a5,%hi(tohost)
    li  a4,1
    sd  a4,%lo(tohost)(a5)
    nop
    csrr    t0,vlenb
    slli    t1,t0,4
    add sp,sp,t1
    ld  s0,56(sp)
    addi    sp,sp,64
    jr  ra
    .size   saxpy, .-saxpy
    .align  1
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    addi    sp,sp,-112
    sd  ra,104(sp)
    sd  s0,96(sp)
    sd  s1,88(sp)
    sd  s2,80(sp)
    sd  s3,72(sp)
    addi    s0,sp,112
    mv  t0,sp
    mv  s1,t0
    li  t0,8
    sd  t0,-64(s0)
    lui t0,%hi(.LC0)
    fld fa5,%lo(.LC0)(t0)
    fsd fa5,-72(s0)
    ld  t0,-64(s0)
    addi    t0,t0,-1
    sd  t0,-80(s0)
    ld  t0,-64(s0)
    mv  s2,t0
    li  s3,0
    srli    t0,s2,58
    slli    a7,s3,6
    or  a7,t0,a7
    slli    a6,s2,6
    ld  a6,-64(s0)
    mv  t5,a6
    li  t6,0
    srli    a6,t5,58
    slli    a1,t6,6
    or  a1,a6,a1
    slli    a0,t5,6
    ld  a1,-64(s0)
    slli    a1,a1,3
    addi    a1,a1,15
    srli    a1,a1,4
    slli    a1,a1,4
    sub sp,sp,a1
    mv  a1,sp
    addi    a1,a1,7
    srli    a1,a1,3
    slli    a1,a1,3
    sd  a1,-88(s0)
    ld  a1,-64(s0)
    addi    a1,a1,-1
    sd  a1,-96(s0)
    ld  a1,-64(s0)
    mv  t3,a1
    li  t4,0
    srli    a1,t3,58
    slli    a3,t4,6
    or  a3,a1,a3
    slli    a2,t3,6
    ld  a3,-64(s0)
    mv  t1,a3
    li  t2,0
    srli    a3,t1,58
    slli    a5,t2,6
    or  a5,a3,a5
    slli    a4,t1,6
    ld  a5,-64(s0)
    slli    a5,a5,3
    addi    a5,a5,15
    srli    a5,a5,4
    slli    a5,a5,4
    sub sp,sp,a5
    mv  a5,sp
    addi    a5,a5,7
    srli    a5,a5,3
    slli    a5,a5,3
    sd  a5,-104(s0)
    sd  zero,-56(s0)
    j   .L5
.L6:
    ld  a5,-56(s0)
    addi    a5,a5,1
    fcvt.d.lu   fa5,a5
    ld  a4,-88(s0)
    ld  a5,-56(s0)
    slli    a5,a5,3
    add a5,a4,a5
    fsd fa5,0(a5)
    ld  a5,-56(s0)
    addi    a4,a5,1
    mv  a5,a4
    slli    a5,a5,2
    add a5,a5,a4
    slli    a5,a5,1
    fcvt.d.lu   fa5,a5
    ld  a4,-104(s0)
    ld  a5,-56(s0)
    slli    a5,a5,3
    add a5,a4,a5
    fsd fa5,0(a5)
    ld  a5,-56(s0)
    addi    a5,a5,1
    sd  a5,-56(s0)
.L5:
    ld  a4,-56(s0)
    ld  a5,-64(s0)
    bltu    a4,a5,.L6
    ld  a3,-104(s0)
    ld  a2,-88(s0)
    ld  a1,-72(s0)
    ld  a0,-64(s0)
    call    saxpy
    li  a5,0
    mv  sp,s1
    mv  a0,a5
    addi    sp,s0,-112
    ld  ra,104(sp)
    ld  s0,96(sp)
    ld  s1,88(sp)
    ld  s2,80(sp)
    ld  s3,72(sp)
    addi    sp,sp,112
    jr  ra
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .word   0
    .word   1073741824
    .ident  "GCC: () 12.0.1 20220505 (prerelease)"
```

This is the log file generated by spike

```
core   0: 0x0000000000001000 (0x00000297) auipc   t0, 0x0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000001000 (0x00000297) x5  0x0000000000001000
core   0: 0x0000000000001004 (0x02028593) addi    a1, t0, 32
core   0: 3 0x0000000000001004 (0x02028593) x11 0x0000000000001020
core   0: 0x0000000000001008 (0xf1402573) csrr    a0, mhartid
core   0: 3 0x0000000000001008 (0xf1402573) x10 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x000000000000100c (0x0182b283) ld      t0, 24(t0)
core   0: 3 0x000000000000100c (0x0182b283) x5  0x0000000000010116 mem 0x0000000000001018
core   0: 0x0000000000001010 (0x00028067) jr      t0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000001010 (0x00028067)
core   0: >>>>  _start
core   0: 0x0000000000010116 (0x00002197) auipc   gp, 0x2
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010116 (0x00002197) x3  0x0000000000012116
core   0: 0x000000000001011a (0xeea18193) addi    gp, gp, -278
core   0: 3 0x000000000001011a (0xeea18193) x3  0x0000000000012000
core   0: 0x000000000001011e (0xf7018513) addi    a0, gp, -144
core   0: 3 0x000000000001011e (0xf7018513) x10 0x0000000000011f70
core   0: 0x0000000000010122 (0xfa818613) addi    a2, gp, -88
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010122 (0xfa818613) x12 0x0000000000011fa8
core   0: 0x0000000000010126 (0x00008e09) c.sub   a2, a0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010126 (0x8e09) x12 0x0000000000000038
core   0: 0x0000000000010128 (0x00004581) c.li    a1, 0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010128 (0x4581) x11 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x000000000001012a (0x464000ef) jal     pc + 0x464
core   0: 3 0x000000000001012a (0x464000ef) x1  0x000000000001012e
core   0: >>>>  memset
core   0: 0x000000000001058e (0x0000433d) c.li    t1, 15
core   0: 3 0x000000000001058e (0x433d) x6  0x000000000000000f
core   0: 0x0000000000010590 (0x0000872a) c.mv    a4, a0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010590 (0x872a) x14 0x0000000000011f70
core   0: 0x0000000000010592 (0x02c37163) bgeu    t1, a2, pc + 34
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010592 (0x02c37163)
core   0: 0x0000000000010596 (0x00f77793) andi    a5, a4, 15
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010596 (0x00f77793) x15 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x000000000001059a (0x0000e3c1) c.bnez  a5, pc + 128
core   0: 3 0x000000000001059a (0xe3c1)
core   0: 0x000000000001059c (0x0000e1bd) c.bnez  a1, pc + 102
core   0: 3 0x000000000001059c (0xe1bd)
core   0: 0x000000000001059e (0xff067693) andi    a3, a2, -16
core   0: 3 0x000000000001059e (0xff067693) x13 0x0000000000000030
core   0: 0x00000000000105a2 (0x00008a3d) c.andi  a2, 15
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a2 (0x8a3d) x12 0x0000000000000008
core   0: 0x00000000000105a4 (0x000096ba) c.add   a3, a4
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a4 (0x96ba) x13 0x0000000000011fa0
core   0: 0x00000000000105a6 (0x0000e30c) c.sd    a1, 0(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a6 (0xe30c) mem 0x0000000000011f70 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105a8 (0x0000e70c) c.sd    a1, 8(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a8 (0xe70c) mem 0x0000000000011f78 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105aa (0x00000741) c.addi  a4, 16
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105aa (0x0741) x14 0x0000000000011f80
core   0: 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3) bltu    a4, a3, pc - 6
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3)
core   0: 0x00000000000105a6 (0x0000e30c) c.sd    a1, 0(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a6 (0xe30c) mem 0x0000000000011f80 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105a8 (0x0000e70c) c.sd    a1, 8(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a8 (0xe70c) mem 0x0000000000011f88 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105aa (0x00000741) c.addi  a4, 16
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105aa (0x0741) x14 0x0000000000011f90
core   0: 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3) bltu    a4, a3, pc - 6
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3)
core   0: 0x00000000000105a6 (0x0000e30c) c.sd    a1, 0(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a6 (0xe30c) mem 0x0000000000011f90 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105a8 (0x0000e70c) c.sd    a1, 8(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105a8 (0xe70c) mem 0x0000000000011f98 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x00000000000105aa (0x00000741) c.addi  a4, 16
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105aa (0x0741) x14 0x0000000000011fa0
core   0: 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3) bltu    a4, a3, pc - 6
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105ac (0xfed76de3)
core   0: 0x00000000000105b0 (0x0000e211) c.bnez  a2, pc + 4
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105b0 (0xe211)
core   0: 0x00000000000105b4 (0x40c306b3) sub     a3, t1, a2
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105b4 (0x40c306b3) x13 0x0000000000000007
core   0: 0x00000000000105b8 (0x0000068a) c.slli  a3, 2
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105b8 (0x068a) x13 0x000000000000001c
core   0: 0x00000000000105ba (0x00000297) auipc   t0, 0x0
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105ba (0x00000297) x5  0x00000000000105ba
core   0: 0x00000000000105be (0x00009696) c.add   a3, t0
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105be (0x9696) x13 0x00000000000105d6
core   0: 0x00000000000105c0 (0x00a68067) jalr    zero, a3, 10
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105c0 (0x00a68067)
core   0: 0x00000000000105e0 (0x00b703a3) sb      a1, 7(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105e0 (0x00b703a3) mem 0x0000000000011fa7 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105e4 (0x00b70323) sb      a1, 6(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105e4 (0x00b70323) mem 0x0000000000011fa6 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105e8 (0x00b702a3) sb      a1, 5(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105e8 (0x00b702a3) mem 0x0000000000011fa5 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105ec (0x00b70223) sb      a1, 4(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105ec (0x00b70223) mem 0x0000000000011fa4 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105f0 (0x00b701a3) sb      a1, 3(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105f0 (0x00b701a3) mem 0x0000000000011fa3 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105f4 (0x00b70123) sb      a1, 2(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105f4 (0x00b70123) mem 0x0000000000011fa2 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105f8 (0x00b700a3) sb      a1, 1(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105f8 (0x00b700a3) mem 0x0000000000011fa1 0x00
core   0: 0x00000000000105fc (0x00b70023) sb      a1, 0(a4)
core   0: 3 0x00000000000105fc (0x00b70023) mem 0x0000000000011fa0 0x00
core   0: 0x0000000000010600 (0x00008082) ret
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010600 (0x8082)
core   0: 0x000000000001012e (0x00000517) auipc   a0, 0x0
core   0: 3 0x000000000001012e (0x00000517) x10 0x000000000001012e
core   0: 0x0000000000010132 (0x60050513) addi    a0, a0, 1536
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010132 (0x60050513) x10 0x000000000001072e
core   0: 0x0000000000010136 (0x0000c519) c.beqz  a0, pc + 14
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010136 (0xc519)
core   0: 0x0000000000010138 (0x00000517) auipc   a0, 0x0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010138 (0x00000517) x10 0x0000000000010138
core   0: 0x000000000001013c (0x5c250513) addi    a0, a0, 1474
core   0: 3 0x000000000001013c (0x5c250513) x10 0x00000000000106fa
core   0: 0x0000000000010140 (0x5ee000ef) jal     pc + 0x5ee
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010140 (0x5ee000ef) x1  0x0000000000010144
core   0: >>>>  atexit
core   0: 0x000000000001072e (0x000085aa) c.mv    a1, a0
core   0: 3 0x000000000001072e (0x85aa) x11 0x00000000000106fa
core   0: 0x0000000000010730 (0x00004681) c.li    a3, 0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010730 (0x4681) x13 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x0000000000010732 (0x00004601) c.li    a2, 0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010732 (0x4601) x12 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x0000000000010734 (0x00004501) c.li    a0, 0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010734 (0x4501) x10 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x0000000000010736 (0x0000a009) c.j     pc + 2
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010736 (0xa009)
core   0: >>>>  __register_exitproc
core   0: 0x0000000000010738 (0xf581b703) ld      a4, -168(gp)
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010738 (0xf581b703) x14 0x0000000000011800 mem 0x0000000000011f58
core   0: 0x000000000001073c (0x1f873783) ld      a5, 504(a4)
core   0: 3 0x000000000001073c (0x1f873783) x15 0x0000000000000000 mem 0x00000000000119f8
core   0: 0x0000000000010740 (0x0000c3b1) c.beqz  a5, pc + 68
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010740 (0xc3b1)
core   0: 0x0000000000010784 (0x20070793) addi    a5, a4, 512
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010784 (0x20070793) x15 0x0000000000011a00
core   0: 0x0000000000010788 (0x1ef73c23) sd      a5, 504(a4)
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010788 (0x1ef73c23) mem 0x00000000000119f8 0x0000000000011a00
core   0: 0x000000000001078c (0x0000bf5d) c.j     pc - 74
core   0: 3 0x000000000001078c (0xbf5d)
core   0: 0x0000000000010742 (0x00004798) c.lw    a4, 8(a5)
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010742 (0x4798) x14 0x0000000000000000 mem 0x0000000000011a08
core   0: 0x0000000000010744 (0x0000487d) c.li    a6, 31
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010744 (0x487d) x16 0x000000000000001f
core   0: 0x0000000000010746 (0x06e84263) blt     a6, a4, pc + 100
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010746 (0x06e84263)
core   0: 0x000000000001074a (0x0000c505) c.beqz  a0, pc + 40
core   0: 3 0x000000000001074a (0xc505)
core   0: 0x0000000000010772 (0x00270693) addi    a3, a4, 2
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010772 (0x00270693) x13 0x0000000000000002
core   0: 0x0000000000010776 (0x0000068e) c.slli  a3, 3
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010776 (0x068e) x13 0x0000000000000010
core   0: 0x0000000000010778 (0x00002705) c.addiw a4, 1
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010778 (0x2705) x14 0x0000000000000001
core   0: 0x000000000001077a (0x0000c798) c.sw    a4, 8(a5)
core   0: 3 0x000000000001077a (0xc798) mem 0x0000000000011a08 0x00000001
core   0: 0x000000000001077c (0x000097b6) c.add   a5, a3
core   0: 3 0x000000000001077c (0x97b6) x15 0x0000000000011a10
core   0: 0x000000000001077e (0x0000e38c) c.sd    a1, 0(a5)
core   0: 3 0x000000000001077e (0xe38c) mem 0x0000000000011a10 0x00000000000106fa
core   0: 0x0000000000010780 (0x00004501) c.li    a0, 0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010780 (0x4501) x10 0x0000000000000000
core   0: 0x0000000000010782 (0x00008082) ret
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010782 (0x8082)
core   0: 0x0000000000010144 (0x3e0000ef) jal     pc + 0x3e0
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010144 (0x3e0000ef) x1  0x0000000000010148
core   0: >>>>  __libc_init_array
core   0: 0x0000000000010524 (0x00001101) c.addi  sp, -32
core   0: 3 0x0000000000010524 (0x1101) x2  0xffffffffffffffe0
core   0: 0x0000000000010526 (0x0000e822) c.sdsp  s0, 16(sp)
```

my toolchain configuration was:

```
../configure --prefix=$HOME/rvv64 --with-arch=rv64gcv --with-abi=lp64 --enable-multilib
```

my spike configuration is:

```
../configure --prefix=$HOME/rvv64 --with-varch=vlen:128,elen=32 --with-isa=rv64iv --with-target=riscv64-unknown-elf
```